# Spring JMS - Unable to connect to broker URL with embedded Broker

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, activemq-classic, message-queue

Here's my JmsMessageSender

```
@Service
public class JmsMessageSender {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;


    /**
     * send text to default destination
     * @param text
     */
    public void send(final String text) {

        this.jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                Message message = session.createTextMessage(text);
                return message;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Simplify the send by using convertAndSend
     * @param text
     */
    public void sendText(final String text) {
        this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(text);
    }

    /**
     * Send text message to a specified destination
     * @param text
     */
    public void send(final Destination dest,final String text) {

        this.jmsTemplate.send(dest,new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                Message message = session.createTextMessage(text);
                return message;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's my DemoClass

```
public class DemoMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // init spring context
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");

        // get bean from context
        JmsMessageSender jmsMessageSender = (JmsMessageSender)ctx.getBean("jmsMessageSender");

        // send to default destination
        jmsMessageSender.send("hello JMS");

        // send to a code specified destination
        Queue queue = new ActiveMQQueue("AnotherDest");
        jmsMessageSender.send(queue, "hello Another Message");

        // close spring application context
        ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)ctx).close();
    }

}
```

My context.xml

and my activemq.xml configuration.

```
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="activemq-data">

        <!--
            For better performances use VM cursor and small memory limit.
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

            Also, if your producer is "hanging", it's probably due to producer flow control.
            For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
        -->

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
                <policyEntries>
                    <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true">
                        <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                             slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                             by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                             For more information, see:

                             http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                        -->
                        <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                            <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                        </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    </policyEntry>
                    <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
                        <!-- Use VM cursor for better latency
                             For more information, see:

                             http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

                        <pendingQueuePolicy>
                          <vmQueueCursor/>
                        </pendingQueuePolicy>
                        -->
                    </policyEntry>
                </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="activemq-data/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>


        <!--
          The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
          use before slowing down producers. For more information, see:
          http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          If using ActiveMQ embedded - the following limits could safely be used:

      <systemUsage>
          <systemUsage>
              <memoryUsage>
                  <memoryUsage limit="20 mb"/>
              </memoryUsage>
              <storeUsage>
                  <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
              </storeUsage>
              <tempUsage>
                  <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
              </tempUsage>
          </systemUsage>
      </systemUsage>
      -->
        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage limit="64 mb"/>
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>
    </broker>
</beans>
```

However when I run my main class this error shows. Did I miss anything in the config?

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://192.168.203.143:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you started the AMQ-broker on tcp://192.168.203.143:61616 ? If not then starting it should solve the problem.

Comment: I have a broker factory on my context.xml

Comment: As per my understanding even after the declaring the factory we need to start the AMQ broker, have a look at this link which provides more details of running the AMQ broke.
http://shengwangi.blogspot.se/2014/10/spring-jms-with-activemq-helloworld-example-send.html
In case if there's any trouble do let me know

Comment: is there anyway to automatically start the AMQ automatically in an embedded setting?

Comment: Yes there is a way for instance you can also download activemq web console for autostarting activemq instance from tomcat. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/activemq-web-console/5.4.2/
Kindly let me know if this helps else I will try to find other suitable options

Comment: Hi, Kindly let me know if this solution helped or if you found better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Had simillar Errors.
Heres solution.

try to connect to borker at your ip address
Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://192.168.203.143:61616.
above mentioned ip address is relevent to Example's System.

[image]

try to run same code for your ip address.(Know your ipAddress in network settings or command "ipconfig")
Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://192.168.1.184:61616.